# Github Webhook not triggered by push via IntelliJ

Tags: github, intellij-idea, webhooks, github-webhook

I've configured a webhook in github, which should be triggered by a push to any branch.

When I edit a file in the github webview, the webhook is being triggered.
But when I edit a file in intellij, the webhook is not being triggered.

Do I have to set some meta data in my git configuration locally or what's the difference to the webview approach?

Comment: Git has never heard of a "webhook"; these things are exclusive to GitHub, and triggered by "GitHub events" (which have little to do with Git itself). There's nothing you can do in Git itself to affect them. See also https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks

Comment: so how do I trigger this webhook locally, is this even possible? @torek

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you read the GitHub docs or ask GitHub directly. I'm no GitHub webhook expert.